# python3.9 and mysql async - Why i'm getting "Task was destroyed but it is pending!"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, aio-mysql

i have a weird problem since i'm using an async mysql driver with Python3.9. I often get this error:

```
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <ClientEventTask state=pending event=on_message coro=<bound method OnMessage.on_message of <cogs.on_message.OnMessage object at 0x7fcb96f50700>>>
```

and I can't find many information about this error in google, the only things I found couldn't help me. So this error occurs at absolutely random times, so I can't exactly reproduce it. But if it occurs, I can directly see it, because he doesn't answer/count/whatever-he-should to a "message."

So a small explanation of what the "on_message" task does is "do something" if a message gets posted by a user. So depending on the number of users and the activity, it can be triggered very often or very rarely. I saw that this error comes most times on bot stop/start-up, but in my case, it occurs sometimes while the bot is running normally. And I don't know what this error exactly means, how can I fix it or why it occurs. I thought maybe is my code for this task too long, but that would not make any sense to me. So that's my code for this "task":

```
    @commands.Cog.listener("on_message")
    async def on_message(self, message):


        if message.author.bot:
            return

        if message.type != discord.MessageType.default:
            return

        if isinstance(message.channel, discord.channel.DMChannel):
            return

        prefixes = ["!", "?", "=", ".", ",", "@", "#", "/", '§', "$", "%", "&", ":?", "*", "<", ">", "-", "bday"]
        for prefix in prefixes:
            if message.content.startswith(str(prefix)):
                return

        global member_cooldown_list
        member_cooldown_list = [i for i in member_cooldown_list if i[1] + cooldown_val > int(time.time())]
        member_index = next((i for i, v in enumerate(member_cooldown_list) if v[0] == message.author.id), None)
        if member_index is not None:
            if member_cooldown_list[member_index][1] + cooldown_val > int(time.time()):
                return

        member_cooldown_list.append((message.author.id, int(time.time())))

        count = 1
        mydb = await getConnection()
        mycursor = await mydb.cursor()
        await mycursor.execute("SELECT ignore_role_id, bonus_role_id FROM guild_role_settings WHERE guild_id = %s", (message.author.guild.id,))
        in_database = await mycursor.fetchone()
        if in_database:
            if in_database[0] is not None:
                role_list = in_database[0].split(" ")
                for roleid in role_list:
                    role = message.author.guild.get_role(int(roleid))
                    if role in message.author.roles:
                        await mycursor.close()
                        mydb.close()
                        return

            if in_database[1] is not None:
                role_list = in_database[1].split(" ")
                for roleid in role_list:
                    role = message.author.guild.get_role(int(roleid))
                    if role in message.author.roles:
                        count += 1

        await mycursor.execute("SELECT ignore_channel_id FROM guild_channel_settings WHERE guild_id = %s", (message.author.guild.id,))
        in_database1 = await mycursor.fetchone()
        if in_database1:
            if in_database1[0] is not None:
                channel_list = in_database1[0].split(" ")
                for channelid in channel_list:
                    if int(message.channel.id) == int(channelid):
                        await mycursor.close()
                        mydb.close()
                        return

        await mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM guild_message_count WHERE guild_id = %s AND user_id = %s", (message.author.guild.id, message.author.id))
        in_database2 = await mycursor.fetchone()
        if in_database2:
            await mycursor.execute("UPDATE guild_message_count SET user_id = %s, message_count = message_count + %s WHERE guild_id = %s AND user_id = %s", (message.author.id, count, message.author.guild.id, message.author.id))
        else:
            await mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO guild_message_count (user_id, message_count, guild_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (message.author.id, count, message.author.guild.id))

        await mydb.commit()
        await mycursor.close()
        mydb.close()
```

I would be really appreciate it, if anyone explains the error to me, a solution for a fix and why it occurs. I really couldn't find much information about it and its really frustrating. Especially, because it occurs since I use an async MySQL driver and python3.9.

**2 days later - Still searching for fix:** I don't found a solution since creation and it's really frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of a race condition between discord client module and the message processing thread as explained in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911782/python-asyncio-loop-exits-with-task-was-destroyed-but-it-is-pending).

> This is because the discord client module needs control once every
> minute or so.
>
> This means that any function that steals control for more than a
> certain time causes discord's client to enter an invalid state (which
> will manifest itself as an exception some point later, perhaps upon
> next method call of client).

In summary, you should offload all the heavy operations to a separate process (not a thread due to the Python GIL). The details are as follows:

1. Discord listener: dispatches the message to the worker server.
2. Worker server: parse message and process SQLs.

In your discord listener, `global` variables should be avoided as follows:

```
....
@commands.Cog.listener("on_message")
async def on_message(self, message):
    import traceback
    if message.author.bot or 
        message.type != discord.MessageType.default or 
        isinstance(message.channel, discord.channel.DMChannel):
        return

    prefixes = ["!", "?", "=", ".", ",", "@", "#", "/", '§', "$", "%", "&",
                ":?", "*", "<", ">", "-", "bday"]
    for prefix in prefixes:
        if message.content.startswith(prefix):
            return
    #global member_cooldown_list
    self.member_cooldown_list = [i for i in self.member_cooldown_list
                                 if i[1] + cooldown_val > int(time.time())]
    member_index = next((i for i, v in enumerate(self.member_cooldown_list)
                         if v[0] == message.author.id), None)
    if member_index is not None:
        if self.member_cooldown_list[member_index][1] + cooldown_val > int(time.time()):
            return

    self.member_cooldown_list.append((message.author.id, int(time.time())))
    guild_id = message.author.guild.id
    try:
        response = await call("process", guild_id)
        ...
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        print (traceback.format_exc())
```

The following codes have to be moved to the work server script as follows:

```
class Handler:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    async def process(self, guild_id):
        count = 1
        mydb = await getConnection()
        ...
        await mycursor.close()
        mydb.close()
        return 0
```

**Note:**

1. You should adopt the code in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911782/python-asyncio-loop-exits-with-task-was-destroyed-but-it-is-pending).
2. You should run the server worker script using `nohup python the_worker_script.py &` or something similar.

Comment: How would a fix look? I don't really understand that, it confuses me. I never worked on errors like this.

Comment: @Razzer Since I have no access to your full codes, I cannot test the code by myself and in fact it is your work. I have wrote a skeleton code according to your original code.